# How to recursively call a function 1 second after an ajax request is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a case where I do not want to call a method every second. Rather, I want to call a function 1 second after the ajax request is completed regardless of the result.

I tried to use the `$.delay()` function but it gives me an error

```
TypeError: $.delay is not a function
```

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
    function checkMessages(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: icwsHandlerUrl,        
            data: {method: 'getMessages', jSON: true},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); // for testing only but this should call a handler for the data  
            },
            complete: function(){
                $.delay(1000, function(){
                    checkMessages();
                });
            }
        });

    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        checkMessages();
    });
});
```

Note: I am using jQuery version 2.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.delay` is used to delay events which are stored in jQuery's event queue. For this you should use JavaScript's own `setTimeout` method instead:

```
setTimeout(checkMessages, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The setimeout will be called every 1 second regardless weather $.json finished or not. I need to make another call only after the first call is done. a second call can't start while another is pending

Comment: Will the `setTimeout` function wait 1 second after it's function finish doing the work or will it keep firing away regardless if it's function finished or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining all of this like this:

```
$(function(){
    function checkMessages(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: icwsHandlerUrl,        
            data: {method: 'getMessages', jSON: true},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); // for testing only but this should call a handler for the data  
            },
            complete: function(){
                $.delay(1000, function(){
                    checkMessages();
                });
            }
        });

    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        checkMessages();
    });
});
```

into this:

```
var req = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: icwsHandlerUrl,        
                data: {method: 'getMessages', jSON: true},
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data); // for testing only but this should call a handler for the data  
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $.delay(1000, function(){
                        checkMessages();
                    });
                }
            });

var nextTask = req.then(function(data){something});
nextTask.done(function(data){somethingelse});
```

the above code will wait everything to be done to do the next task. Try it out.

Make sure you remove the `$.delay()` and put it into the `req.then()` function.

Here is the `.then()`explanation https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

**EDIT:**

```
$(window).load(function{
     $.delay(1000, function(){
         checkMessages();
     });
});
```

and place check messages outside of this piece of code.

Comment: Good thought, but will I need .then and .done?  should I only need .then? But I will still need my code to sleep for 1 second before the making another ajax request

Comment: if you need requests to be made then the delay should go out of the entire function, and have it go in the load, here I'll show you. But in my opinion you should stick with original JavScript function `setTimeout()` instead of `$.delay()`

Comment: that edit above will do me no good for couple of reasons. I get the same error I started out with "$.delay method does not exists. second, I need the delay to take place after the ajax request is done.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers contain all the essential bits, but here's a complete solution:

```
$(function(){
    var checkMessagesTimeout;

    function checkMessages(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: icwsHandlerUrl,        
            data: {method: 'getMessages', jSON: true},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); // for testing only but this should call a handler for the data  
            },
            complete: function(){
                checkMessagesTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    checkMessages();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

    }

    $(window).load(function(){
        checkMessages();
    });
});
```

This version has the added benefit of storing the timeout's reference into a variable, so should  the need arise, you can abort the timeout before the next ajax call is made, by calling `clearTimeout(checkMessagesTimeout);`

Comment: wouldn't this code only delay the only the second request? the first request will take place as soon as the page loads, then the second request will kick in 1 second after the first request is complete then after that every second regardless of the complete status?

Comment: @MikeA this code will call `checkMessages()` 1 second after the previous call has been finished, regardless of whether that call succeeded or failed. The first call is made when the page has been loaded. If you'd like to delay the first call as well, just change `checkMessages();` to `setTimeout(function() { checkMesages(); }, 1000);`

Comment: I need to implement a delay exactly 1 second from the time a request is completed. if there is a system delay and the request took 5 seconds then no additional requests will be fired until the respond finish. the code you present waits for the first request to finish and then it fires one request every second after thats

Comment: @MikeA No, it works as you specified: it fires a new request one second after the previous one has been completed, not once every second. Please try it to see for yourself.

Comment: Okay. so your saying that setTimeout will wait 1 second after it's function finish?

Comment: @MikeA Yes, that's specified with the second argument, which is 1000ms = 1 second in this case. In the code I posted, once the ajax request is done, whether it succeeds or fails, the `complete` handler will be called, which will begin a 1 second timeout, after which the request will be made again, after which a 1 second timeout will begin, etc... until you call `clearTimeout(checkMessagesTimeout);`